# playoff probability between two teams.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am working on this probability question:

```
Suppose in the Minor Hockey League Championship play off series between
Pirates and Thunders, there are three possible play off games planned. 
A team that wins two games is declared the champion. 
Outcome of each game is either a win or a loss - there are no ties! 
The first game is played in the Pirates Arena, 
the Second game is played in the Thunder's arena, 
and if required the third game will be played in the Pirates arena. 
A team wins with a probability of 2/3rd in its home arena, 
and with a probability of 1/3rd in the opposition's arena. 
What is the probability that Pirates will be declared the Champion?
```

and I do not have any clue how to approach this question. if anybody could help me on this one ill really appreciate it.

Comment: Pirates can win the series in the following ways: PP, PTP, TPP. Find the probability of each and add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of the Pirates winning the first two games is 2/9.

The probability of the Pirates winning, losing, and then winning, is 8/27.

The probability of the Pirates losing the first, and then winning the next two, is 2/27.

Overall, the probability of the Pirates winning the series is 16/27, or around 59%.